# angular 2 template reference variable

Tags: angular

i have a little issue with understanding template variable reference, when used with NgForm, here is what in the angular2 doc :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(theForm)" #theForm="ngForm">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!theForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> What is the value of theForm?
>
> It would be the HTMLFormElement if Angular hadn't taken it over. It's
>   actually ngForm, a reference to the Angular built-in NgForm directive
>   that wraps the native HTMLFormElement and endows it with additional
>   superpowers such as the ability to track the validity of user input.

i understand what theForm value, but i don't get from where we get the `ngForm` variable, is it a property of the NgForm directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> exportAs - name under which the component instance is exported in a
>   template

The ngForm is the Angular form directive.

You can **expose** your directive to the view as local variables with the **exportAs** key.

From the source code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup]),ngForm,[ngForm]',
  exportAs: 'ngForm'
  ...
})
```

Now you can access the ngForm directive API in your template as ngForm.

When you write this:

```
#theForm="ngForm"
```

What it does is create a local variable to your template and assign it's value to the form directive.